# does morphia supports automatic timestamp?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Does anyone knows if morphia supports automatic timestamp for create/update of documents in a collection in mongodb during its create/modify operations.

I have already come to know that this support is not available in mongodb. I would like to know if there is any way to get the last access/update time of data or documents in morphia driver.

Thanks,
sadish

Answer (score 7):

I'm generally using a base entity, which all other entities extend. It provides the ObjectId, creation date, last change date, a disabled flag,...

The relevant code snippets look like this:

```
protected Date creationDate;
protected Date lastChange;

// Getters and setters or final setters which don't do anything,
// if you only want to allow the entity to update the values

@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    creationDate = (creationDate == null) ? new Date() : creationDate;
    lastChange = (lastChange == null) ? creationDate : new Date();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry in advance if this isn't the exact answer you're looking for.  But the short answer is no.

There appears to be no API in the latest **Morphia** which supports that operation.  Maybe there is a bug opened to support this.  In the meantime, you should use your favorite constructor for java.util.Date or java.sql.Timestamp.

The source code for **Morphia** has the appropriate converter built in to handle this [TimestampConverter.java](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/main/java/org/mongodb/morphia/converters/TimestampConverter.java).

Only tangentially related.  If your reason for using `$currentDate` is to avoid clock skew problems among multiple hosts, then you're barking up the wrong tree.  Though not explicitly stated in the `$currentDate` documentation, it is documented that **MongoDB** does nothing to address clock skew among various hosts.  This can be found in the [documentation for ObjectId.getTimestamp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/).  Therefore, the usage of `$currentDate` is going to provide little benefit as opposed to time-stamping in the client side.

Comment: Try to put the link for the bug stated in your answer. It will improve your it and make it easier to readers to track it.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to put more than two links :D

Comment: Try to use the comments. Then someone can edit the answer with it.